# Decomposing data from a json withangularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a json file that is requested from a server so i can't modify how is sent, but all the data i need is there, so i want to put that data into the charts, the thing is how i can break down the json file, because the relevant  data is nested, the structure is

> estados(array of object)
>
> > id (property)
> >
> > name (property)
> >
> > localidades (array of object)
> >
> > > id (property)
> > >
> > > name (property)
> > >
> > > type1 (object)
> > >
> > > type2 (object) etc..

i need to retrieve the id data from the object *estados* and *localidades* then especific data one of the objects nested in localidades.

How i can do that? i only know how to go through every nested object by iteration, but decomposing it?

here is a json sample :
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=9cd4c3af94f14b1cca2d35226794ea78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) library (Or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), if you prefer) is what you are looking for. You can use it to manipulate your collections any way you want (pretty much). You could potentially do without helper libraries, but it is much easier (and sometimes faster, though browser dependent [[ref]](https://jsperf.com/native-vs-array-js-vs-underscore/8)) to do it this way.

Here are some examples in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdj6pc7k/) I put together for a demo. Some example of how to access particular property of an object inside an array of objects:

```
$scope.findObjects = function () {
    var estado = _.find($scope.allJson, {
            "idEstado": $scope.idToSearch
        });

    $scope.exampleOutput = _.filter(estado.localidades, function (item) {
        return item.demanda && (item.demanda.ata > 5);
    });
};
```